# TYPO3 backend: search custom records

Tags: search, typo3

I developed an extension which allows creation of new records.

In List module, under the records list, there is the Search form.

It works with fe users for example, but not with my custom records.

Is there any special configuration that I have to add in my tca to make this form work with my custom records?

**EDIT**: This seems to be happening after updating to TYPO3 4.6. In the previous version, 4.3.3, it works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit `ext_tables.php` file in `typo3conf/ext/yourext` directory, find your table, and add to its `ctrl` section `searchFields` property as comma separated list of fields to search in:

```
$TCA['tx_yourext_table'] = array(
    'ctrl' => array(
        'title' => 'Title of your table',
        'label' => 'title',
        'tstamp' => 'tstamp',
        'crdate' => 'crdate',
         // etc...
        'searchFields' => 'title, other_field, yet_other_field',
    ),
);
```

Don't forget to clear all caches after that, works at `4.6.3`

There's [official information](http://wiki.typo3.org/TYPO3_4.6#Live_Search) when and why it was changed

Comment: Nice feature! Is it a way to do that in TYPO3 4.5 LTS?