# Typo3 group Records by a DB field

Tags: typo3

Im using a Page (type Folder) to show all records with this pid. Is it possible group these records somehow? Theres a field in my DB called "vid", which contains the uid of some other records. I want the records in my folder to be grouped by this uid. Any suggestions? (Using Typo3 4.6.3)

Comment: Do you really want to group or did you mean search or filter? Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751197/typo3-backend-search-custom-records

Comment: i really need something like grouping the records depending on the field "vid" (the values are uids int(11) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, then the simple answer is No. Grouping is not possible with the default backend list view module. You can sort, and search/filter there, but not more. You may write a custom backend module that does the trick for you.

What I could also imagine is to use the export function in the list module (there is a button somewhere) and then do the grouping with your favorite spreadsheet tool (like excel). Depending on how often you need this feature that may be a simple workaround that does not require and additional coding.

Comment: thanks.. im waiting for more answers. if not i accept this soon.